# L2 Sequencer Uptime feed

Tags: chainlink, chainlink-keepers

In L2 sequencer uptime feeds, why **timeSinceUp <= GRACE_PERIOD_TIME** and not **timeSinceUp < GRACE_PERIOD_TIME** if  **timeSinceUp == GRACE_PERIOD_TIME** is allowed, will that cause any problem.

or can I implement that, just want to make sure it will not cause any issue. Or should I just follow chainlink implementation strictly.

In testing it doesn't give any issue or problem. But maybe something goes wrong on mainnet, as also different L2 has different mechanism for calculating block.timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

@Shashank, thanks for your question.  I encourage you to read this [blog](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on asking questions more effectively so that you increase your chances of getting a useful answer, quickly. Your question, presently, is quite vague and gives little information that would help people help you.

I understand you're referring to Chainlink data feeds.

In the linked docs, the comments above the relevant lines are

```
// Make sure the grace period has passed after the
// sequencer is back up.
```

This logic require the grace period to have passed.

If you do only < and not <= then the grace period may not have fully passed.  The last second, within the grace period, would be treated as out of the grace period.

If you do that then the earlier instruction "This helps you prevent mass liquidations by providing a grace period to allow customers to react to such an event" in the docs will be slightly modified, right? the customers will have 1 second less in their grace period.

Perhaps test with that edge case where the timeSinceUp == GRACE_PERIOD_TIME inside that logic, but the condition is timeSinceUp < GRACE_PERIOD_TIME.